# How to add Multi-pick list field to Compact Layout of Task in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, tasks, activities, compact-layout

I have a Multi-pick list field in Activity, I want that field to be added in Compact layout of Task object.

The Compact layout displays all the fields in the Available field section except Multi-pick list field. I need the Multi-pick list field to be displayed in the available section.

Please help me in accomplishing the above.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** display a multi-select picklist in a compact layout. Refer to the below excerpt of unsupported field types in compact layout from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=compact_layout_overview.htm&type=5).

> Compact layouts support all field types **except**:
>
> - text area
> - long text area
> - rich text area
> - **multi-select picklist**

Comment: Okay. Thank You so much.
Is there any other way that I can display Multi-pick list field to be available on Task during the creation of a record, while that Task is related list of Opportunity/Accounts etc..(In Lightning Experience)

Comment: That classifies as a separate question. You may like to open a new one with details.

Comment: Okay. Definitly.